# SQL Server - Inner Join On - Like Partial Match

Tags: sql, inner-join, string-matching

I have two tables

```
    Table 1 Customers
    Table 2 Statement
```

I want to do an inner join query with a on - like statement that would partial match the Name column.

For Example

```
     Statement.Name
     MCGILL UNIVERS.  
     CANADIAN BLOOD BPY 
     OTTAWA HOSPITAL  
     VANCOUVER COAST

     Customers.Name
     McGILL UNIVERSITY
     OTTAWA HOSPITAL CLINICAL INVESTIGATION UNIT
     CANADIAN BLOOD SERVICES
     Vancouver Coastal Health Authority
```

I tried running a inner join on like with a LEFT string:

```
     SELECT     ['Govt Customers$'].*, Statement.* 
     FROM       ['Govt Customers$'] Inner Join
                  Statement
                  on Statement."Adjusted Comment" 
                  like Left (['Govt Customers$'].[Customer Name],11)
```

It returned no results, so I am not sure where my error is.
I can't do a full text lookup becuase my tables are not indexed.
Please let me know if anyone can help. I am newer to SQL so any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: are you missing the '%' sign?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the first 11 characters, you need to take the left of both sides of that join.  You also may have issues with certain characters being considered wildcards or pattern characters with the `LIKE` operator.